# Как повесить выполнение метода на форму action html формы?

Tags: php, html

Перейду сразу к сути.
Есть метод класса

```
class HomeController {
    public function update($id)
    {
        $update->table('tasks')           // update this table
        ->cols([                    // update these columns and bind these     values
        'id' => 'id',
        'title' => 'title',
        'content' => 'content', 
        ]);

        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($update->getStatement());
        $sth->execute($update->getBindValues());
        $myTask = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header("Location: /tasks"); exit;
    }
}
```

Хочу повесить выполнение этого метода сюда в экшн

```
<form action= "" method="post">
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Роутинг — это маршрутизация: входящий URL разбирается специальным образом и по его результату выполняется определенный код (или как в вопросе метод класса). С роутингом напрямую связано понятие ЧПУ (человекопонятные урлы), которое позволяет исключить в адресах сложные параметры. Например вместо [http://сайт/admin/new-page](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/admin/new-page) пришлось бы использовать [http://сайт/admin.php?action=new-page](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/admin.php?action=new-page)

Примеры готовых систем маршрутизации:

1. https://github.com/bramus/router
2. https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute
3. https://github.com/izniburak/php-router
4. https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute
5. https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Router

[Статья "PHP-роутинг (Routing) для новичков"](https://maxsite.org/page/routing)